# Swift - Location Prompt not happening soon enough

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, locationmanager

I am building a location-based app that lists nearby coffee houses. App keeps crashing on first build on device because location keeps returning as nil.

This is because the Privacy - Location prompt isn't happening soon enough, even though though the request is earlier in the code. After I close the app after it crashes, that's when I'm prompted to allow my location.

I have three onboarding screens, and when I get to this tableviewcontroller, that's when it crashes.

If I go into Settings > Privacy > Location and manually enable location services, the app works great.

Here's my code (I removed a ton of unnecessary stuff):

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ShopTableViewController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {




@IBAction func filterBack(_ sender: Any) {
        getLocale()
        shops.sort() { $0.distance < $1.distance }
        shops.removeAll()
        loadShops()
        sortList()

}


//MARK: Properties

var shops = [CoffeeShop]()
var filteredShops = [CoffeeShop]()
var objects: [CoffeeShop] = []
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
func checkLocationAuthorizationStatus() {
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
var currentLocation = CLLocation!.self
var userLatitude:CLLocationDegrees! = 0
var userLongitude:CLLocationDegrees! = 0
var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 1.0, longitude: 1.0)
var refresher: UIRefreshControl! = UIRefreshControl()





func getLocale() {

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    userLatitude  = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
    userLongitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
    print("\(userLatitude), \(userLongitude)")
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    /// self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    checkLocationAuthorizationStatus()

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    {
        getLocale()

    }

    let locValue = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate
    noHeight()
    loadShops()
    sortList()
    print("\(locValue?.latitude), \(locValue?.longitude)")

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ShopTableViewController.handleRefresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)


    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        shopTable.refreshControl = refresher
    } else {
        shopTable.addSubview(refresher)
    }


}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the conditional in checkLocationAuthorizationStatus wrong? e.g. Should be `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedWhenInUse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` is an asynchronous method, so your method that wraps it `checkLocationAuthorizationStatus()` is also async.

However, in your `viewDidLoad`, you call

```
checkLocationAuthorizationStatus()

self.locationManager.delegate = self
self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

This is triggering the locationManager to start before it is authorized.  Take a look here at this (somewhat old) link http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/

### Example

Be sure to conform to `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    } else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == . authorizedWhenInUse {
        startTrackingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        startTrackingLocation()
        // ...
    }
}

func startTrackingLocation() {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    getLocale()
    //not clear which of these methods require location
    let locValue = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate
    noHeight()
    loadShops()
    sortList()
    print("\(locValue?.latitude), \(locValue?.longitude)")
}
```

Comment: So I need to move some things around? 

I'm having a hard time translating that article to my code.

Sorry for the newb-ness

Comment: Thank you! I've gotta move some other stuff around now to make sure the table updates it's data after the location tracking starts, and this entirely relieved my headache!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the authorization response before using location services.
What you are doing now is requesting the authorization and the immediately starting location services. You need to be sure, the app is authorized before getting location.

Comment: Can this be done by moving things around (restructuring)?

Comment: @scttcrry basically yes.